# How to start counting time at the start of my program in C

Tags: c, time, sleep

I'm making a game in which you must hack a system like: type numbers you see on the screen: 12345 in 10 seconds. I wonder how to warn a player when 10 seconds elapse, like print on the screen "Too slow!!!!!!". I tried `sleep()` function, but it stops the program, while the `sleep()` function is running!

Rules:
When you start the program, appears on the screen:

```
Enter code:           Hack 1.
```

If you type 1 and enter appears a random number you have to overwrite. If you fail appears:

```
Hacking failed!!!!!!!!.
```

If you're too slow it appears:

```
Too slow!!!!!!!
```

But that thing "Too slow!!!!!!" happens only at the end of the program!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    time_t start, end;
    double need;
    int i;
    double number;
    int t = 15;
z:
    printf("Enter the code:                    Hack 1  :");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == 123456789)
    {
        printf("Enter the room.");
    }
    if(i == 1)
    {
        printf("You've got %d seconds. Press 1 to start hacking the system:", t);
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if(i == 1)
        {
            //Appears a random number and time starts counting
            time (&start);
            srand(time(NULL));
            double rn = (rand() % 1000000000000000000);
            printf("%f type here: ", rn);
            scanf("%lf", &number);
            if(number == rn)
            {
                //Time ends
                time (&end);
                //Calculate elapsed time
                need = difftime (end, start);
                //If you're too late
                if(need > t)
                {
                    printf("Too late!!!!!!!!!!!");
                }
                else
                {
                    //If you success
                    printf("System hacked. Enter the room. ");
                    t--;
                    goto z;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //If you fail
                printf("Hacking failed!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read about `for` loops and `while` loops.

Comment: Your program execution must block while it waits for user input. If you want to print "Too Late" after 10 seconds while simultaneously waiting for someone to enter input you will have to use another thread

Comment: A naive answer might be to set an alarm, but that's hard to get right. You need to dive into the deep and complex field of event-driven programming, and perhaps structure your program around a central event loop (like epoll, with timerfds).

Comment: You think: while (time < 10)              if(answer == 123456)  printf "Cool" else "Oh" .If the time is less than 10 seconds it' a chance to type the answer?

Comment: To repeat: This is not easy. There is no simple, straight-forward trick. There are a number of approaches, but they all require that you think about your program in a fundamentally different way.

Comment: I would suggest to implement timeout functionality in your program, though it'll take some serious efforts to implement them.

Comment: You probably need some newlines at the ends of at least some of your `printf()` statements.  You need to check that `scanf()` works; if the user types `a` instead of `1`, the program is not going to be happy.  You'll need to implement some sort of timed read, which might (on Unix at least) be best implemented with the `read()` system call and some non-negligible supporting function calls, followed by using `sscanf()` (rather carefully) to get the input converted.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it but it needs `conio.h` which is usually not available outside Windows and DOS. It checks for keyboard input while also looking at the timer.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TIMEOUT 10

int main(void)
{
    int code;
    int entry;
    int key;
    time_t mark;
    time_t now;

    mark = time(NULL);
    srand((unsigned)mark);
    code = rand();
    printf("The code is %d\n", code);
    printf("Enter the code\n");
    entry = 0;

    while (entry < code) {
        while (!_kbhit()) {
            now = time(NULL);
            if (now - mark > TIMEOUT) {
                printf("\nTimeout failure!\n");
                exit (1);
            }
        }
        key = _getche();
        entry = entry * 10 + key - '0';
    }

    if (entry == code)
        printf("\nSuccess\n");
    else
        printf("\nIncorrect code\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
The code is 19911
Enter the code
1984
Timeout failure!
```

More program output:

```
The code is 20326
Enter the code
29881
Incorrect code
```

And again:

```
The code is 20156
Enter the code
20156
Success
```

Comment: POSIX has nothing to say about `<conio.h>`; that is a Windows-only (or, at least, Windows-mainly) header.  There might be Unix ports for the code, but it is not a Unix (POSIX, etc) header by default.

Comment: This is a very bad idea since you are doing a busy wait for an extended period of time. This causes 100% CPU consumption until the 10 seconds are over.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I mentioned POSIX (since edited out) because the MS documentation for `kbhit()` and `getch()` says of both *"this POSIX function is deprecated. Use the ISO C++ conformant _kbhit (_getch) instead."*

Comment: Beware prejudices on display (mine, that is!).  Microsoft wouldn't know a POSIX function if it came across one.  When I request the use of POSIX, I expect to use the POSIX names — as written in the standard. If I include a POSIX header (say `<unistd.h>`), then the POSIX names should be exposed. I'd accept 'with `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` defined' or similar as OK, though a bit heavy-handed. Then the functions should be exposed because I requested them. The Windows functions shouldn't be exposed unless I request them (e.g. `#include <windows.h>`) either — parity is parity. But that's not what MS thinks.

Comment: MS exposes its functions (which also fall into the namespace reserved for users) willy-nilly. That's more or less OK on Windows. The comment is used by MS to derogate 'foreign' functions. The 'rename with leading underscore' does place the names into the namespace reserved by standard C 'for the implementation', but POSIX defines that the functions should be available, at least if you request them (though for POSIX-only headers, including the header should be sufficient, and generally is sufficient). Anyway, I'm sure that POSIX never defined `kbhit()` or `getch()` — or specified `<conio.h>`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, the `conio.h` remark was my mis-wording. I agree the answer above is unsatisfactory. It was an attempt to get round the input blocking behaviour of the standard input functions (without getting involved with OS).

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix-like operating system such as Linux, you would use `alarm()` to set a timer and then read from standard input. When the timer elapses, a `SIGALRM` is delivered and the `read` system call is interrupted. You can observe this happening by checking the result of `read` and the value of `errno`. Here is a rough example of how you could do this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void handle_alrm(int signo) {}

/* ... */
ssize_t count;
char linebuf[81];

signal(SIGALRM, handle_alrm);  /* establish a signal handler */
alarm(10);                     /* schedule a SIGALRM in 10 seconds */
count = read(STDIN_FILENO, linebuf, 80);
if (count > 0)
    remaining_time = alarm(0); /* turn off the alarm */
    linebuf[count] = '\0';
    printf("You took %d seconds\n", remaining_time);
    /* do something here ... */
else if (errno = EINTR) {      /* assume the alarm was delivered
    puts("You were too slow!");
    /* do something here ... */
} else {
    /* some other error occured */
    /* do something here ... */
}

signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);
```

This probably also works if you use `fgets()` instead of `read()`.

Another approach that does not involve signals is to use the `select()` function. It allows you to wait for data to be ready on a file descriptor with a specified time out. This might better for your task as it does not involve signal handling. This function is from the BSD socket API and is probably not available on Windows. It might be part of Winsockets though.